# How to increase the `DropDownHeight` of `RadComboBox` that contains `Templates`

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net, telerik, radcombobox

I have a `RadComboBox` as below :-

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBoxNames" runat="server" Width="470px" DropDownAutoWidth="Enabled" MaxHeight="363px" Skin="MySkin" EmptyMessage="Select"
                HighlightTemplatedItems="True" DataValueField="ID" DataTextField="ID" OnDataBound="RadComboBoxNames_DataBound" >
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    <table style="width: 250px; text-align: left">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold; width: 60px;">ID</td>
                            <td style="font-weight: bold; width: 180px;">Name</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table style="width: 250px; text-align: left">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="width: 60px;"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "ID")%></td>
                            <td style="width: 180px;"><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Now my `DropDown` height is not `363px`   as I have set in the `MaxHeight` property, it is very small and not increasing my `dropdown` height even if I Increase the value in `MaxHeight` property !!

How to increase my `DropDownHeight` of my `RadComboBox` ? Do I have to use any styling  techniques ?  Please Help, ThankYou.

Answer (score 0):

You can alternatively change the `MaxWidth` of the `RadComboBox` drop down area by editing the default theme of `RadComboBox`.  To do that, follow these steps:

1. Open your project in Blend and with RadComboBox selected  go to **Object-> Edit Template -> Edit a Copy**
2. Search for a Control Template with an `x:Key="NonEditableComboBox"`
3. Inside, find Popup `x:Name="PART_Popup"`
4. Add a MaxWidth property that equals a value which you see fit to your needs.

Hope it would help.

Comment: thanks a lot , but any way I found the answer, it's very simple, just keep the `Height` property of the RadComboBox !!!

Comment: I have just checked your question again, I dont see any relationship between `width` and `MaxHeight` of your `RadCombobox`

Comment: sorry it's Height (not width) , I have edited my question now !

Answer (score 0):

Just keep the `Height` property of the `RadComboBox` !!